# How to make a new google sheet tab with a name specified in a cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make something that takes a text input from a cell, and when you click a button, it will make a new sheet, and name it the text you put in the cell. Here,:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y47Jv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

First, get the value from the cell with the [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue()) method:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var newSheet = sheet.getRange("B4").getValue();
```

It returns a String, so you can use it with the [create](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#createname) method:

```
SpreadsheetApp.create(newSheet);
```

Then, create the button from Insert > Drawing and assign the function to it.

**EDIT**

Since the question was about Sheets and not Spreadsheets, I'm adding the solution for it:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var newSheet = sheet.getRange("B4").getValue();

sheet.insertSheet(newSheet);
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertSheet(String)

Comment: It doesn't work for me, it says finished script, but it doesn't actually make a new sheet.

`function addSheet() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var newSheet = sheet.getRange("B4").getValue();

  SpreadsheetApp.create(newSheet);
}
`

and, I've assigned the correct script to the button.

Comment: Actually, nevermind, it has, but it doesn't appear in the same spreadsheet I'm using. I just opened up google sheets, and it had like 30 spreadsheets with the names I've inputted before. I think I'm thinking about TABS, not SHEETS. Sorry.

Comment: Oh I see. It's fine, I updated my answer with the code for sheet tabs.

Comment: It gave me this error: TypeError: Cannot find function insertSheet in object Sheet. (line 6, file "addSheet")Dismiss

Comment: Yes, I forgot to remove `getActiveSheet()` from the other code. I corrected it now, sorry.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that! Please, consider accepting my answer, so other's can see it works without reading the comments :)